# Which operator do I have to overload?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

Which operator do I have to overload if I want to use sth like this?

```
MyClass C;

cout<< C;
```

The output of my class would be string.

Comment: BTW, you should consider reading an entry-level book to C++. It could make things a lot easier.

Comment: Not a bad question just because you know the answer...

Comment: What are the C++ operators in that statement? There is only one and so that is what you will have to overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you've to overload `operator<<` as:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyClass & obj)
{
   //use out to print members of obj, or whatever you want to print
   return out;
}
```

If this function needs to access private members of `MyClass`, then you've to make it `friend` of `MyClass`, or alternatively, you can delegate the work to some public function of the class.

For example, suppose you've a point class defined as:

```
struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

Then you can overload `operator<<` as:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const point & pt)
{
   out << "{" << pt.x <<"," << pt.y <<"," << pt.z << "}";
   return out;
}
```

And you can use it as:

```
point p1 = {10,20,30};
std::cout << p1 << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
{10,20,30}
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/zjcYd

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks good but im getting an error that the operator << can't have that many parameters? Any ideas?

Comment: @Julian: You should post the code. Or else how can I say what is the problem?

Comment: Nevermind I found the error. Thought I had to put the declaration into the class.

Answer (score 1):

The stream operator: <<

You should declare it as a friend of your class:

```
class MyClass
{
    //class declaration
    //....
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyClass& mc);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyClass& mc)
{
    //logic here
}
```

Comment: You do not need to declare it as a friend.

Comment: Agreed... but you should for 2 reasons: first off, easier access to members, which you should have, since it's part of the class logic, and second and more important, stream operator overloads can be defined anywhere in the code. You need to be able to access them anywhere, not just to compilation module you're using. Say you declare it in a cpp... you'll only be able to use it there, unless declared in the header.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `operator<<` as a free function.